# php mailer in function generates error

Tags: php, server, phpmailer, internal-server-error

I created a function to handle email sending using PHPMailer

this is the function:

```
function sendEmail($from, $replyTo, $to, $subject, $message) {
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.pickbyclick.ro';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->Username = 'admin@pickbyclick.ro';
$mail->Port = 25; 

$mail->setFrom($from, 'Pick by Click Team');
$mail->addReplyTo($replyTo);
$mail->addAdress($to);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = emailShowNice($message);
$mail->AltBody = $message;
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

}

And after this call

```
sendEmail($from, "no-reply@pickbyclick.ro", $to, $subject, $message);
```

It shows 500 error server. Can anyone please help me?

Edit: this is the emailShowNice function

```
function emailShowNice($message) {

$order   = array('\r', '\n', '\r\n', "\r", "\n", "\r\n");
$replace = ' <br /> ';

$mes = str_replace($order, $replace, $message);

return $mes;
}
```

Comment: what's the error in your apache or httpd log?

Comment: what is the function `emailShowNice` ? my guess is that its something in that.

Comment: i couldn't find all logs in cPanel, they are not from today

Comment: `function emailShowNice($message) {

 $order   = array('\r', '\n', '\r\n', "\r", "\n", "\r\n");
 $replace = ' <br /> ';

 $mes = str_replace($order, $replace, $message);

 return $mes;
}` This is the function.

Comment: try this on the top of your file error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: This is the error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::addAdress() in /home/r34187pick/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 34

Comment: i misspelled 'address'

Comment: sorry for the post then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line a mistake here

```
$mail->addAdress($to);
```

with

```
$mail->addAddress($to);
```